# How do I read the whole file in wchar_t buffer on Win32?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file, buffer

I'm having trouble reading a file in UTF8 encoding into a `wchar_t` buffer as I don't know the file size in advance.

Does anyone know how I can read the whole file in a buffer?

I imagine I'd have to keep a `wchar_t *` (pointer) and resize it as I read. However that sounds very scary as I haven't ever resized pointers before.

I'm doing Windows C++ programming with Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: Use `realloc` to "resize" a pointer.

Comment: Consider std::wstring instead of wchar_t[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using a vector?

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

:::

std::wifstream in(file_name);

//Will automatically reallocate to the require size
std::vector<wchar_t> store {
    std::istream_iterator<wchar_t, wchar_t>(in),
    std::istream_iterator<wchar_t, wchar_t>()};

//to access wchar_t* you can call data();
my_func(store.data());
```

Comment: I hadn't considered using a vector. Let me try!

Comment: @bodacydo, using a vector is a much more C++ friendly approach, dealing with raw pointers is really C and should be avoided where possible, vectors are much less error prone.

Comment: @bodacydo also don't forget that if you want newlines and spaces you need to set no skip ws and std::ios::binary on the file.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please show how to set std::ios::binary and also set no skip? I'm not that experienced. (Can you please update your example?)

Comment: Hi Again @111111. Unfortunately your example gives me `error C2228: left of '.data' must have class/struct/union` on Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: We ran into `vexing parse` problem! Wow. http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=767929

Comment: Hmm and now I'm getting a new error: `error C2039: 'data' : is not a member of 'std::vector<_Ty>'`

Comment: @bodacydo hmm, `data()` should be a member, try `&store[0]' instead. That most vexing parser is a PITA :)

Comment: @111111 `data` was only recently added to `vector`, so isn't in VC++ 2008.

Comment: @PeterWood, I know the formalisation of data happened in C++11, but I was fairly sure it's existence in the standard was older than that? Anyway the address of index method should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to allocate a buffer the size of the file you first need to find the file size.  To do that, you call the stat() function, with appropriate arguments, and it fills in a field containing the file size.

Suppose you store that size in the variable `filesize`.

Then you can

```
wchar_t *buffer = reinterpret_cast< wchar_t * >new char [ filesize ];
```

and then read the whole file into that buffer, using read(), after having called open() on it to get a file descriptor, or  fread() after having called fopen() to get a FILE *.

Comment: Thanks! I've a follow-up question - should I read the file in `wchar_t` or first read it in `char` and then convert `char` to `wchar_t`?

Comment: read() and fread() think they're working with a (unsigned) char buffer.  But they don't really care.  The trick is that the size of the buffer is relative to bytes, since stat gives you the file size in bytes.  But make it a pointer to wchar_t and you can treat them as wchar_t after the read is done.